# Is there a way to make a recursive struct/enum boxed as default?

Tags: struct, enums, rust, box

If I try to define a recursive struct/enum in Rust:

```
enum Enum {
    A,
    B(Enum),
    C(Enum, i32),
    D(Enum, Enum),
    ...
}
```

I will get a compilation error, as expected.

I know that one possible solution to that problem is to wrap all the recursive references with `Box<T>` like this:

```
enum Enum {
    A,
    B(Box<Enum>),
    C(Box<Enum>, i32),
    D(Box<Enum>, Box<Enum>),
    ...
}
```

or even provide a `type` alias:

```
type Enum = Box<InnerEnum>;    

enum InnerEnum {
    A,
    B(Enum),
    C(Enum, i32),
    D(Enum, Enum),
    ...
}
```

This made me wonder if it is possible to do it automatically somehow? I there any macro like this?

```
#[boxed]
enum Enum {
    A,
    B(Enum),
    C(Enum, i32),
    D(Enum, Enum),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since you can't check for equality of tokens in regular macros, this would have to be done in a procedural macro, which would be alot of work to do, instead of just writing out all of the `Rc`s and `Box`es yourself.

Comment: and what would be the gain of such feature ?

Comment: While you could make a procedural macro replacing all `Enum` with `Box<InnerEnum>`, this would be tricky to do properly. For example you don't want to end up with `Vec<Box<InnerEnum>>`, so you'd need to special case this and many other cases. And given that you barely ever have to box recursive types, there would be little benefits to such a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to stay with the classic approach of explicitly writing out the whole enum.

But - regarding your question of possibility - I think it can be done (to a certain extent):

```
macro_rules! boxed_enum{
    ($dummy: ident, enum $E: ident $($variant:tt)* ) => {
        pub mod $dummy {
            type $E = Box<$dummy>;
            pub enum $dummy $($variant)*
        }
        type $E = $dummy::$dummy;
    }
}

boxed_enum!(InnerEnum, enum Enum {
    A,
    B(Enum),
    C(Enum, i32),
    D(Enum, Enum),
});
```

The macro takes a `$dummy`, which is both the name of an auxiliary `mod`ule and an auxiliary `enum` (as described in your trick), and type-aliases the dummy-enum to your desired identifier.

I think it is possible to generate the `$dummy` from `$E` so that the user does not need to specify this explicitly. However, this would rely on `concat_idents` (iirc, nightly-only) or other crates such as `paste`.

As said, I'd go with a manual solution in this case.

Comment: I am not a fan of the question, as it asks to obfuscate the code for minor aesthetic gains, but I am impressed by the ingenuity of this answer. Well done sir!

Comment: Yeah, this answer is definitely a smart way to solve the problem, but I think explicit code in this case is better.